# How to make TableCell with full Table width with MaterialUI in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I got a table, which is looking like this:

```js
import { Typography, Table, TableHead, TableRow, TableCell, TableBody } from '@material-ui/core';

const Example = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <Table>

        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="center"><Typography> 1 </Typography></TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center"><Typography> Some </Typography></TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center"><Typography> Some</Typography></TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center"><Typography> Some </Typography></TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center"><Typography> Some </Typography></TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>

        <TableBody>
          
          {
            // Here I'm loading some async data 
            // Meanwhile it's fetching I want to display some loading indicator
          }

        </TableBody>
      </Table>

    </>
  )
}
```

And in the TableBody before I display a normal TableRows with data I want to display to users loading indicator that is in the middle of the table. So basically I need one TableCell inside this table that is taking all the columns width, so then I will be able to center my indicator.

How can I achieve that using MaterialUI Components and their API to make my table look like this:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can expand the cell which you want to include the loading indicator like the following.

[Table DOM structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces) should be considered.

```
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
        {
          !isLoaded
            ? <TableRow>
            <TableCell
              colSpan={5} // it seems each line has 5 table cells
              align="center"
            >
              <LoadIndicator />
            </TableCell>
            : <TableBody>
      ...
        }
```

2. Using component props.

```
      <Table component="div">
         <TableHead component="div" />
        {
          !isLoaded
            ? <LoadIndicator>
            : <TableBody component="div">
                ...
        }
      ...
```